# Showing the product rule for the Euclidean connection wrt the Euclidean metric.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm confused about a few things in Lee's book on Riemannian geometry. On page 67, Lee writes that it is easy to compute the following in terms of the standard basis where $\overline{\nabla}$ is the Euclidean connection, and the norm below is the Euclidean metric: 
\begin{equation}
\overline{\nabla}_X\langle Y, Z\rangle = \langle \overline{\nabla}_X Y, Z\rangle + \langle Y, \overline{\nabla}_X Z\rangle
\end{equation}
Now, I know that the Euclidean connection is characterized by having all its Christoffel symbols equal to $0$, and the Euclidean norm is $\overline{g} = \delta_{ij}dx^i dx^j$. Here are some points of confusion:

1. First, $\overline{\nabla}$ is a linear connection, meaning that I'm expecting it to be a map of the form $\nabla: \mathcal{T}(M) \times \mathcal{T}(M)\to \mathcal{T}(M)$, where $\mathcal{T}(M)$ is a smooth section of the tangent bundle of a manifold $M$ (in this case I'm really thinking about $M$ as Euclidean space). Alternatively, $\langle Y,Z\rangle$ is a real number. However, there is a natural identification between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T_p \mathbb{R}^n$, which would allow this discussion to make a little more sense. Is it implicit that I should be thinking about the real number $\langle Y, Z\rangle$ as being part of a smooth section of the tangent bundle on Euclidean space?
2. I haven't been able to actually show that this equality is true. I thought I would write down what I've gotten thus far in coordinates, and hope that someone would offer some suggestions:

$$
\langle \overline{\nabla}_X Y, Z\rangle + \langle Y, \overline{\nabla}_X Z\rangle =
\langle (XY^j) d_j, Z^i d_i\rangle + \langle Y^i d_i , (XZ^j)d_j\rangle
$$
Because $\overline{\nabla}_XY = (XY^j)d_j$ as part of the definition of the Euclidean connection. I know how to expand $(XY^j)d_j$ in coordinates, but I think that ultimately there is something I'm missing here in terms of using the basis $dx^i$ for the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and feel that I'm missing something implicit in the left hand side of the equation (namely, that there is this identification between real numbers and an element in the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at a point, but I still can't see exactly how the right hand side and left hand side are equal when the right hand side should clearly be a real number, and the left hand side needs some kind of 'conversion' in my mind in order to become considered as a real number). Any help, or recommended reading is most appreciated!

Comment: In the page [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128128/riemannian-connections-how-to-understand-overline-triangledown-x-langle-y?rq=1), a point was made that on page 53, it is established that you can talk about connections $\overline{\nabla}_X f$ where $f$ is a smooth function, yielding $Xf$. In this case, we think of $g$ as being a smooth function. I think I now understand how to think about this situation, and it only remains for me to actually calculate this in coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\overline{\nabla} _X Y = XY^j d_j$, you should get

$$
\langle \overline{\nabla}_X Y, Z\rangle + \langle Y, \overline{\nabla}_X Z\rangle =
\langle (XY^j) d_j, Z^i d_i\rangle + \langle Y^i d_i , (XZ^j)d_j\rangle
$$

instead of

$$
\langle \overline{\nabla}_X Y, Z\rangle + \langle Y, \overline{\nabla}_X Z\rangle =
\langle (XY^j) d_j, Z^i d_i\rangle + \langle Y^i dx_i , (XZ^j)dx_j\rangle
$$

As the metric is Euclidean,

$$\langle (XY^j) d_j, Z^i d_i\rangle + \langle Y^i d_i , (XZ^j)d_j\rangle = (XY^i)Z^i + Y^i (XZ^i) = X(Y^iZ^i) = X\langle Y, Z\rangle\ .$$

Comment: Yeah, I should've updated this question with this calculation, I figured this out not too long after I posted my first comment. Just a remark, I understand what you wrote in the first line - but it seems like it's just a difference in notation and nothing more substantial than that, no? Lee uses the notation that I wrote down instead of $d_j$, but means the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: You're right again, I've edited the original post.